# AIC drop & non-significativity after ARIMA-GARCH

Tags: arima, model-selection, aic, garch

After having modelled conditional variance via an appropriate ARIMA(p,d,q) model I inspected the squared residuals ACF and noted that it does not look like a realisation of white noise.

Therefore (after an appropriate test on ACF) I decided to model an ARIMA(p,d,q)-GARCH(1,1), with p,d,q the same I got from the maximisation of the AIC of the ARIMA model.

The estimates of the garch parameters look very significant, however the AIC has dropped from the one I got with simple ARIMA. Moreover, Log-likelihood moved from positive to negative and many of the previously estimated ARIMA parameters now look non-significant.

These are the outputs from 3 similar series I modelled for comparison. As we can notice the problem i described is present for all the three:

- ARIMA

[image: ARIMA]

- ARIMA-GARCH

[image: ARIMA-GARCH]

Questions:

- How can it be possibile?
- Why it happened? Should I maybe redo the maximisation of the ARIMA(p,d,q) parameters *jointly* during ARMA-GARCH estimation? (i.e. calculate ARMA(**1**,**0**)-GARCH(1,1), ARMA(**0**,**1**)-GARCH(1,1), ARMA(**1**,**1**)-GARCH(1,1),  and so on and keep the one with max AIC)
- Should I allow higher orders GARCH (e.g. GARCH(2,1), GARCH(2,2))?

Comment: How were you able to *not* do the maximization jointly and yet calculate the AIC of the ARIMA-GARCH model? Did you fit an ARIMA-GARCH model with restrictions on ARIMA parameters?

Comment: @RichardHardy thank you for your comment. I added further details on my question. What did i meant is that I didn't calculate ARMA(1,0)-GARCH(1,1), ARMA(1,1)-GARCH(1,1) and so on but simply took ARMA(5,5) as the one that maximised the AIC in the plain ARIMA model.